# wpython directory listing and displaying particular format

Tags: python, python-2.7

1) The below statement works fine

```
test_suite_name = [name for name in os.listdir(".") if (os.path.isdir(name))]
```

but I need to see the directories inside "./squish".

```
test_suite_name = [name for name in os.listdir("./Squish") if (os.path.isdir(name))]
```

but this statement is not working... please tell me how can i correct it, i think some correction is needed for the if statement.

2) Also what script format i should use to display the folder which begins with "test_"  say,

i have many folders, some are prifixed with "test_", these folders can be in folder structure above or below where the script is placed.

the "test_" folders can be any where under /xyz/abc folder which can be folder any where above or below where the python script is sitting

Comment: `os.listdir('.')` is equivalent to `os.listdir()` and `os.listdir('./Squish')` is equivalent to `os.listdir('Squish')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For question number one:

```
 test_suite_name = [name for name in os.listdir("./Squish") if os.path.isdir(os.path.join("./Squish", name))]
```

As for your second question, there are two things you can do:

1) Use the full path; for example: `r'C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe'`

2) Say your script is located in `C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop`, and you want to specify file `log.txt` that is located in the `C:\Documents and Settings` folder.

You can use `'..'` to specify the parent direcotory of your current location. So if you are in `C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop`, then `r'..\..\log.txt'` will refer to `C:\Documents and Settings\log.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You see, the `name` variable in the iterator contains a particular file or directory name only, **not** the whole path. So,

```
path = './Squish'
dirs = [name for d in os.listdir(path) 
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, name))]
```

should do.

Note, that you have to sort the list manually (e.g. via `sorted(dirs)` ) due to the nature of `os.listdir()`.

Comment: it says NameError: global name 'path' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

1) The problem is, that name is just the name of the subdirectory, i.e. `test` and not `./Squish/test`.

use `os.path.isdir(os.path.join('.', 'Squish', name))` instead.

In case you look up folders in `.`, it is no proble because isdir looks in the current directory given a relative path.

2) you can extend your list comprehension to

```
[name for name in (...) if os.path.isdir(...) and name.startswith('test_')]
```

Comment: (...) is not a valid syntax ? i am using python 2.6.5

Comment: I am sorry, i missed your comment. (...) stands for the part you should insert yourself.